# Jax-rs CRUD. Проблема с ошибкой Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, html, crud, jax-rs

Ошибка: HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

Используя jax-rs создал CRUD приложение на формах HTML. Но есть проблема, когда используешь PUT или DELETE в самом HTML, то формы не работают, всегда выкидывает вышеуказанную ошибку. Используя GET или POST, могу выполнить те же функции, но мне интересно, можно ли задействовать указанные методы в HTML CRUD.

Много гуглил на инглише, но так и не увидел положительного ответа, вдруг у нас знают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни в одном из браузеров не реализована поддержка других HTTP-методов, кроме GET и POST. Если в атрибут `method` тега `form` прописать PUT, например, браузер отправить POST.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.